# How to render alternate show view in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app, my 'show' view renders a submitted form. I'd like to create an 'info' view that displays different data from the same submitted form. It's basically an alternate show view.

I put this into my controller, but it doesn't work:

```
  def show
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  end

  def info
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'info'
  end
```

All it does is display the 'show' view. How do I correct this?

Comment: This may be weird, but can you try `render :layout => "info"` Also layouts are different than views. If you are in the `UsersController` doing `render 'info'` will render `app/views/users/info.html.erb` where as `render layout => "info"` will render `app/views/users/info.html.erb` with layout `app/views/layouts/info.html.erb`

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do. Do you sometimes want to use the show view and sometimes want to use the info view. Or are you completely replacing the show view?

Comment: not replacing the show view...I want to be able to view both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lie elsewhere, because those two actions look fine. In this example, your `show` action should use your `show` view, and your `info` action should use your `info` view (albeit with a layout also called "info" - you might want to consider renaming that so you don't get confused between your layout and your view).

Are you sure your routes are set up properly? Do you have an 'info' route set up for your `Form` model? i.e.

routes.rb:

```
resources :forms do
    get :info
end
```

And are you navigating to the right URL? (in this case, *http://yourhost/forms/123/info*)?

Comment: I tried what you suggested...didn't work. I think the problem does lie with the routes. Clicking on the 'show' view goes to: http://localhost:3000/forms/4. Is it possible to click on the "info" link, go to the same address, but just view the data differently?

Comment: No, each url goes to only one action, you'll need to set up a route like this and then link to /forms/4/info, try form_info_path(form).

Comment: Further to the comment above, not only is that not possible (without specifying some kind of switch elsewhere), you *shouldn't* do that. You want the representation of the data you see at a URL to be predictable. As stated above, use your `info` action.

Answer (score -1):

You can call

```
 def info
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
     render :action => 'show'
 end
```

and it will use the @form instance variable defined in the info method, make sure you have the proper routes setup